# How to protect / prevent pushing a specific branch to one repository, but not another?

Tags: git, bash

How to protect pushing a ***specific*** branch **to one repository**, but **not another** on UNIX machine?

Using git hooks:

```
$ cd PATH_TO_LOCAL_GIT_REPO 
$ cd ./git/hooks
$ nano pre-push
```

Pre-push file contents (in my case the ***specific*** branch is **master**):

```
#!/bin/bash

protected_branch='master' 
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]
then 
    echo -e "Master branch is protected from push."
    exit 1 # status 1 protects from pushing
else  
    exit 0 # status 0 continues pushing
fi
```

This code protects from pushing master branch to **any** repository. So I need to make another condition, checking the repository name. Basically, I need to get the repository name the git is currently pushing to.

Comment: Do you have to use hooks? With gitolite you could achieve this very easily.

Comment: I am not sure. Gitolite is an auth layer and I am using github at the moment. Not sure if I consider using it.

Comment: Probably not then. gitolite is for self-hosting. You cannot really enforce access restrictions on the client side. Everybody is free to add or remove hooks as they wish.

Comment: I see, this is for my personal protection, I never said I do it for access control. I just do not want to accidentally push master branch to public repo (as it contains sensitive data), but still want to push to my private deployment repo.

Comment: A tip: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` is equivalent to but more idiomatic than `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,'`.